# Determining latency in threads that use sleep_for using SCHED_FIFO

Tags: multithreading, real-time, latency

I have a Linux embedded system built with PREEMPT_RT (real time patch) that creates multiple SCHED_FIFO threads, with a priority of 90 each. The goal is that they execute without being preempted, but with the same priority.

Each thread does a little bit of work, then goes to sleep using std::this_thread::sleep_for() for a few milliseconds, then gets scheduled back and executes the same amount of work.

Most of the time, each thread latency is impeccable, but once every minute or so (not an exact regular interval) all threads get hogged at the same time for one second or more (instead of the low milliseconds they usually get called at).

I have made sure Power management is disabled in the kernel kconfig, I have called mlockall() to avoid memory getting paged out, to no avail.

I have tried to use ftrace with wakeup_rt as the tracer, but the highest latency recorded was around 5ms, not nearly enough time to be the cause of the issue.

I am not sure what tool would be best to identify where the latency is coming from. Does anyone have ideas please?

Comment: It's possible this is due to a system management interrupt, but frequent delays of greater than 1 second sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: When I run the same system application without SCHED_FIFO (just using the default SCHED_OTHER with the CFG scheduler), then my jitter is much worse but I don't experience any spike that is so high. I am making a bunch of SysFs calls (for GPIO and SPI), I wonder if it could suddenly flush? Or is preempt getting disabled by some IRQ?

Comment: Also, this embedded linux solution is running on a ARM Cortex-A9. I thought SMM was only for x86, but I may be wrong?

Comment: The system management interrupt I was mentioning is for x86, and I would be very surprised if any reasonably modern processor inserted delays of over 1 second. Have you run cyclictest (I assume it works on ARM)? If so, does it also experience large delays?

Comment: I did run cyclictest and it ran well. I found the issue was a thread writing to disk (Disk I/O). The thread was SCHED_OTHER, so I am not sure how it affected the SCHED_FIFO threads, but it seemed disabling this thread fixed the problem.